# split vertical text file with unknown number of spaces

Tags: python, nlp

I need to split a text file vertically and automatically to get the left and the right section,i have so many files and not all files have the same index of sections but they all have 2 parts

[image]

my code is using regex with space space char to find the benign of the second section

```
lis=[]
import re
with open('name.txt', 'r') as f:
   speech = f.read().splitlines()

for line in speech:
   lis.append([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(r'\s\s\S', line) ])
flat_list = [x for xs in lis for x in xs]
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(flat_list)
counts
```

but this return me many possibilities and even when i use most_common counts i dont get always the good index of the right sections

```
Counter({(43, 46): 22,
        (63, 66): 22,
        (46, 49): 6,
        (67, 70): 5,
        (68, 71): 3,
        (66, 69): 1,
        (59, 62): 1,
        (75, 78): 3,
        (64, 67): 1,
        (71, 74): 6,
        (72, 75): 1})
```

this work is to get blocks from resumes and most of resumes have 2 part the left and the right and no rules of the length of each part

Comment: does the file use tabs to position the second column, or just spaces?

Comment: just spaces, the files are resumes, they were in pdf format that i transformed to txt file using pdftotext

Comment: if it's not formatted with tabs then I think you can just slice each line, e.g. iterate over the lines and `left_column.append(line[:40])` `right_column.append(line[40:])` (where `40` would be whatever character position the right-hand column starts at, e.g. how many spaces before `FORMATIONS`)

Comment: this is the probleme it's not always 40, in some cases the left side is biger then right one so it could be 63 ou 75 and even

Comment: can you share the actual text you need to parse?  it's going to be hard to help otherwise, unless you can clearly define the parsing rule in the question